# Online websites for recent research in Mathematics

Tags: functional-analysis, graph-theory, reference-request, research

May someone suggest me some online websites for recent research in Mathematics where I can found all quality research up to date. Currently I am working on fixed point theory endowed with graph. I simply googled this title but not able to find recent work. I know about google scholar, arxiv. Are there any other websites? Thanks

Comment: Probably the simplest first steps to take is to look for papers by people currently working in this field (look at their personal and/or academic web pages), and then look at the bibliographies of those papers for other papers and other people to search for, and after a while you'll be completely lost in a sub-sub-tunnel of the rabbit hole you started down.

Comment: www.mathoverflow.net is the stackexchange for professional Mathematicians. If you formulate a thoughtful question asking for references, you'll get good information. If you're expecting a site that has everything ever done in Mathematics, forget it.